# How to get rolename from Roles object in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am doing this to get roles of a user:

```
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

After that a simple loop through can serve the purpose like this:

```
foreach(var r in roles)
{
  if (r.Name == "School")
  {
  }
}
```

Now, I am stuck in knowing what should be the property of object r. Can you answer this very basic stuff?

Comment: What's your question? What do you want to do? What does or doesn't this code do? That method returns an `IList<string>`.

Comment: [GetRolesAsync(user) ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_GetRolesAsync__0_) will return a `Task<IList<String>>`

Comment: string does not contain a definition for 'Name'. I just want to know role of the user.

Comment: they are given as strings

Comment: i.e. just use `if (r == "School")`.

Comment: Simply, the result `UserManager<TUser>.GetRolesAsync` is already a list of the role names, not a list of an object like `IdentityRole`. There's no property you need to access because `r` in the your `foreach` is *already* the role name.

Comment: @KirkLarkin please make an answer specifying this, i.e. just use if (r == "School")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UserManager<TUser>.GetRolesAsync(TUser)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) returns a `Task<IList<String>>`. In your example, you're using `await`, which means your `roles` variable becomes of type `IList<String>`. When iterating through `roles` with your `foreach` statement, each `r` value within the loop is simply of type `String`. It's obvious that `String` does not contain a property named `Name` and as such, the error makes sense.

It appears you were expecting `r` to represent a complex type (perhaps an [`IdentityRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityrole?view=aspnetcore-2.1)), but as it's simply a string here, you can just compare `r` directly, like this:

```
foreach(var r in roles)
{
    if (r == "School")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get `object` of `Role` using Identity, you have List of object with many property like: `User`,`Id`, `Name`, `NormalizeName`, and something like this. You can trace and see those.

You have to know that what do you want.

If you want to check `userRoles` with system `Roles` you can write you code like:

```
var roles = await _roleManager.Roles.TolistAsync();
var userRolesName = await _userManagment.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Now! you have list of roles that user have, and you have all roles.and with this code you get object of roles that user have like:

```
var userRoles = userRolesName.Where(x=>userRolesName.Contain(x.Name));
```

With this code you have object of Roles that user have.and you can process them.